Lambda not being triggered despite seemingly proper EventBridge rule setup?
I have an EventBridge rule that captures all resource modifications from Cloudtrail:
{
  "source": ["aws.*"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["*.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["Create*", "Delete*", "Update*", "Put*", "Attach*", "Detach*", "Modify*", "Set*"]
  }
}

Its target is a lambda that was tested with a cloudtrail event, and it works (sends the response to Teams channel webhook).
This is the CF YAML of the rule, so you can have a clearer insight into it:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: CloudFormation template for EventBridge rule 'infrastructure-drift'
Resources:
  EventRule0:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventBusName: default
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.*
        detail-type:
          - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
        detail:
          eventSource:
            - '*.amazonaws.com'
          eventName:
            - Create*
            - Delete*
            - Update*
            - Put*
            - Attach*
            - Detach*
            - Modify*
            - Set*
      Name: infrastructure-drift
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Id: xxx
          Arn: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxx:function:InfrastructureDrift


I made some manual changes to some resources on my account, which are supposed to trigger the Lambda, but they never did. I can get the lambda to work when I test it with any event from Cloudtrail personally, meaning its formatted well and it does its job. I feel like the issue is with the rule, but I don't see how, as this looks right to me. I should note that the lambda has right Resource-based policy. Any help appreciated, thank you. Just in case, this is the lambda:
import json
import http.client

def format_json(json_data):
    """ Helper function to format JSON data into a pretty-printed string """
    return json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Extract basic information about the event
        user_identity = event.get('userIdentity', {}).get('arn', 'Unknown user')
        event_name = event.get('eventName', 'Unknown event')
        event_time = event.get('eventTime', 'Unknown time')

        # Detailed description of the change from requestParameters and responseElements
        request_details = format_json(event.get('requestParameters', {}))
        response_details = format_json(event.get('responseElements', {}))

        # Construct the message to be sent to Teams
        message = (f"**Event Time:**\n{event_time}\n\n"
                   f"**User:**\n{user_identity}\n\n"
                   f"**Action:**\n{event_name}\n\n"
                   f"**Request Details:**\n```\n{request_details}\n```\n\n"
                   f"**Response Details:**\n```\n{response_details}\n```")

        # Teams webhook URL
        webhook_url = 'xxx'

        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("xxx.webhook.office.com")
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        payload = json.dumps({
            "title": "AWS Resource Change Alert",
            "text": message
        })

        conn.request("POST", webhook_url, payload, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        return data.decode("utf-8")
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle generic exceptions and print error details
        print(f"Error processing event: {str(e)}")
        return str(e)



To debug this you should first go to the EventBridge dashboard, and go to the rule, and click the "Monitoring" tab. Now look at the metrics like "MatchedEvents" and "Invocations" to see if the rule is actually firing on those events you expect it to fire on. If it is, look at the "FailedInvocations" metric to see if perhaps there is some error happening when it tires to call your Lambda function. If it appears to actually be triggering the Lambda function, then check the Lambda's metrics and logs for any errors.

@MarkB Thanks for the response. Absolutely no invocations or matched events, which I find really weird considering I see those events myself in Cloudtrail.

Perhaps it is this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446882/cloudwatch-rule-set-to-trigger-from-cloudtrail-doesnt-trigger-lambda-function-u

There's already a trail enabled, and I can see the events in a cloudwatch log group, so it shouldn't be that. Do I need to do some specific setup with it, or does it just need the trail to exist there?

It looks like you've done everything you need to already. Sorry I don't have an answer for you. It sounds like it's definitely an issue with the EventBridge rule, and nothing is even getting to your Lambda function yet. I would try an EventBridge rule for one specific API action, verify you can get it to fire, and slowly start adding in the * wildcards and repeat. One thing I can't find is any example of a wildcard in the source attribute, so I wonder if that is even supported.

You should also use this tool https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-pattern-sandbox.html to take an event from CloutTrail and make sure your event filter properly matches it.

It was fixed by removing all wildcards from the rule, its insane that I have to hardcode every service and action I need. I have my lambda do the filtering where I need it. Thanks for trying. I'll accept your answer, just post it, thanks :)

I would experiment some more to see if some wildcards will work.
